# How to wait for promise to complete?

Tags: node.js, express, spotify

I'm using [Spotify Web Api Node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) to make api calls.

My problem is that I'm redirected before getMe api call has returned data...

How to wait for results then redirect ?

Sorry I'm new to NodeJS and Express.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET callback. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('callback worked!')
    var code = req.query.code || null;
    // var state = req.query.state || null;
    // var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;


    req.app.settings.spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
            console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
            console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);

            // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);

            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.getMe().then(function(data) {

                if (typeof req.session.user === 'undefined') {
                    req.session.user = {};
                }

                // never gets here
                console.log(req.session.user);

                req.session.user.display_name = data.body.display_name
                req.session.user.email = data.body.email
                req.session.user.id = data.body.id
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
            });

        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
        });

    res.redirect(302, '/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It's redirecting first because your res.redirect is outside of your callbacks. Put your res.redirect inside of your getMe().then(...) at the very end, or put another .then() after your last function(err) and do the res.redirect() in there

Answer (score 2):

If you need redirect as a final step after both error or success, then try this solution:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET callback. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('callback worked!')
    var code = req.query.code || null;
    // var state = req.query.state || null;
    // var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;


    req.app.settings.spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
            console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
            console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);

            // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);

            return req.app.settings.spotifyApi.getMe().then(function(data) {

                if (typeof req.session.user === 'undefined') {
                    req.session.user = {};
                }

                // never gets here
                console.log(req.session.user);

                req.session.user.display_name = data.body.display_name
                req.session.user.email = data.body.email
                req.session.user.id = data.body.id
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
            });

        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
        })
        .then(() => {
          res.redirect(302, '/');  
        })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Here is my working code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET callback. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('callback worked!')
    var code = req.query.code || null;
    // var state = req.query.state || null;
    // var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;


    req.app.settings.spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
            console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
            console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);

            // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);


        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
        })
        .then(function(data) {

            req.app.settings.spotifyApi.getMe().then(function(data) {

                req.session.user.display_name = data.body.display_name
                req.session.user.email = data.body.email
                req.session.user.id = data.body.id

                console.log(req.session.user);
                res.redirect(302, '/');

            }, function(err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
                res.redirect(302, '/');
            });

        });

});

module.exports = router;
```